# validate combo box in CodeIgniter

Tags: validation, combobox, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter 3 where i am trying to validate my two combo boxes.

My code is like this:

view:

```
<tr>
     <td >
        <?php $extra=' class="selectCombo"';
            $busVal=array();
            $busVal[]="Select";
            foreach($values as $val){
                $busVal[$val->bus_id]=$val->bus_no;
            }
        echo form_dropdown('bus_id', $busVal,set_value('bus_id'),$extra);
        ?> 
       </td>
       <td><?php echo form_error('bus_id');?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td >
        <?php
            $extra=' class="selectCombo"';
            $route=array();
            $route[]="Select";
            foreach($values as $val){
                $route[$val->route_id]=$val->route_name;
            }
            echo form_dropdown('route_id',$route,set_value('route_id'),$extra);
            ?> 
           </td>
           <td><?php echo form_error('route_id');?></td>
</tr>
```

My controller code is like this:

```
public function add()
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules('bus_id', 'Bus', 'trim|required|callback_check_Bus');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('route_id', 'Route Name', 'trim|required|callback_validate_route');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    echo 'Error';
}else{
  }
}
public function check_Bus($val){
        if($val ==0)
        {
          $this->form_validation->set_message('select_validate', 'Please Select Bus.');
          return false;
        } 
        else
        {
          return true;
         }
    }

     public function validate_route($val){
        if($val ==0)
        {
          $this->form_validation->set_message('select_validate', 'Please Select Route.');
          return false;
        } 
        else
        {
          return true;
         }
    }
```

I get following message for both fields:

> Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Bus.(check_Bus)
>   Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name
>   Route Name.(validate_route)

What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code working fine.

```
callback validation rule
callback_fieldname_check        
//function name callback_fieldname_check (){

}

// Set message - fieldname_check
```

see code

```
public function add()
{

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('bus_id', 'Bus', 'trim|required|callback_bus_id_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('route_id', 'Route Name', 'trim|required|callback_route_id_check');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('load_your_view');
        }else{
        echo "Added";
        }
}
public function bus_id_check($val){
        if($val ==0)
        {
          $this->form_validation->set_message('bus_id_check', 'Please Select Bus.');
          return false;
        } 
        else
        {
          return true;
         }
    }

     public function route_id_check($val){
        if($val ==0)
        {
          $this->form_validation->set_message('route_id_check', 'Please Select Route.');
          return false;
        } 
        else
        {
          return true;
         }
    }
```